# Получить индекс значения массива java

Tags: java, массивы

Есть строковый массив системных шрифтов fontNames. Как узнать какой индекс у элемента массива, значение которого `Times New Roman`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вернёт индекс элемента в массиве `String`:

```
String[] s = {"Arial", "Colibri", "Times New Roman", "Windings", "FontMacOS"};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s).indexOf("Times New Roman"));
```

Пример на [ideone](http://ideone.com/l5Xcf4).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Реально помогло! :)

Answer (score 7):

Обратите внимание, что `Arrays.asList(s).indexOf()` работает только с объектами. Т.е.

```
int[] s = {0, 1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s).indexOf(1));
```

всегда будет выдавать "-1".